# Class 'ViewController' has no initializers

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a ZigZag app and I don't think I did anything wrong but it gives me this error saying what the title says. I do not know how to fix it can you please help me on this? Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you've forgotten to inherit from UIViewContoller.

Comment: Can you show your code and the error message?

Answer (score 0):

its seems you forgot to initialize your variables.

E.g. Instead of `var a`  intialize it as `var a = String()`